# How can i make an ER Diagram for a Database which has single table in it

Tags: mysql, entity-relationship

In my project, there are basically 3 different databases used. For example, the first database is for login sign up.

It contains only one table with one entity that is a user with two attributes that is email and password. So how can I make ER Diagram for a database having a single table and having no relationships?

Comment: Read question carefully

Answer (score 2):

Simply use a rectangle for the `User` and two circles for `email` and `password` that are connected to the rectangle. Like the following image:

[image: Entity-Relationship Diagram of the user table]

If the `email` is the *primary key*, you can underline it like the image shows.

This [ER Diagram template of a Surgeon](https://creately.com/diagram/example/gstx57ng2/Database+of+a+Surgeon) for instance has one entity as well. Of course an ER diagram is usually used to make a graphical representation of a complex database (with multiple entities, relations, etc.).

Comment: Thanks a ton @Willem